# ipython notebook anchor link to refer a cell directly from outside

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am writing documentation for a notebook-based framework. When referring to important cells in a demo-notebook, can I point to a particular cell by using some sort of anchor?

For example if I have the demo-notebook at  127.0.0.1/mydemo, is it possible to refer to the input cell In[10] by some anchor tag like 127.0.0.1/mydemo#In10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference a IPython notebook cell in markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080066/how-to-reference-a-ipython-notebook-cell-in-markdown)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not on stable, and only on Header(1-6) cell on master. Just click on the header cell and it will put the right anchor in the url bar, wich is usually `#header_title_sanitized`
Using the prompt number is not a good idea as it might change. It will be supported on nbviewer as well, we are working on it.

Comment: IPython 1.0 is "due" mid July, feature is already on master for adventurous. No ETA for nbviewer, probably around the same time.

Answer (score 25):

Creating internal links within Markdown works quite well in practice for me. For example, you can make a table of contents by making a list in a markdown cell at the top of the page.

```
*[jump to code cell 2](#cell2)
*[jump to code cell 3](#cell3)
*[jump to code cell 4](#cell4)
```

Then you just insert a markdown cell right above the code cell you want to link to (say code cell 2). Just add one line of code:

```
<a id="cell2"></a>
```

See this tutorial for more explanation: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/python_reference/blob/master/tutorials/table_of_contents_ipython.ipynb

Comment: Thanks! I will try this. Note that I am looking the links to work from outside html pages, not within the same notebook.

Comment: It will still work... `<a href="http://yournotebook.com#cell2>Jump to code cell 2</a>`. Also clicked any header in a notebook will produce an internal link, e.g. http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/python_reference/blob/master/tutorials/table_of_contents_ipython.ipynb#2.-The-internal-hyperlink

Comment: I love the table of contents idea!

Answer (score 7):

I like to use headers to organize my notebooks, such as

```
#My title
```

in a markdown cell. In another location, I can then refer to this cell using

```
[Link to my title](#My-title)
```

in markdown (looks like you should replace spaces with hyphens).

I got this from a more complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28080529/386279).