# How to reference a IPython notebook cell in markdown?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

How do I reference a cell in a IPython notebook markdown?

I know how to make a reference to an external link. But is there a way to assign an ID to a cell and then refer to the cell in the markdown?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Yes, there's way to do just that in IPython.

First, define the destination in the cell you want to link with a `html` anchor tag and give it an `Id`. For example:

```
<a id='another_cell'></a>
```

*Note* - When you run the above cell in markdown, it will become invisible. You can add some text above the anchor to identify the cell.

Second, create the internal hyperlink to the destination created above using Markdown syntax in another cell and run it:

```
[Another Cell](#another_cell)
```

Now, clicking on link should take you to the destination.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer whether or not it is possible to reference to a certain code cell and if so, how?

Comment: @Joma It's easy if you're only interested in navigation. If the code cell is already preceded by a Markdown cell, then you need only place the anchor tag at the end of the preceding Markdown cell.

If not, (e.g. you have two consecutive code cells and want an anchor for the second one) you could just create an "invisible" Markdown cell above your code cell, as Amit mentions, containing the anchor tag.

Comment: How do you add a subsection? Like a, b, c under 1.

Comment: this blog post has more useful information: http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_ipython_internal_links.html

Comment: Hmm, this appears not to be working on Google Colab

Comment: Is anyone able to do this on google colab?

Comment: This is also not working well in vscode. Some links work but others dont for no reason.

Answer (score 71):

If you want to link directly to a specific section of your notebook, it can be useful to use this code: `[section title](#section-title)`. Note that, for the text in the parentheses, you should replace spaces and special characters with a hyphen.

As an example, consider this case in which we want to insert a link to the section 'Univariate + One step ahead':

[image: Section that I want to link]

To do so, we just need to add the code `[Univariate + One step ahead](#Univariate-+-One-step-ahead)`:

[image: Code to create the link]

This way we avoid the introduction of an anchor tag, since the section title already acts as one.

Comment: Good call on the replacing spaces with a hyphen! Definitely was making that mistake!

Comment: Good idea, but this approach will not produce the expected outcome if the hyperlink is a title itself, in which case clinking the hyperlink will jump to itself. Example: anchor is `## Univariate` (`##` = 2nd level title), if then one wants a hyperlink to that anchor by setting *e.g.*: `### [Univariate](#Univariate)`, clinking on it will bring the hyperlink itself to the top of the page, not the expected section.

Comment: This didn't work for me on azure...

Comment: @calocedrus is right. However, one can bypass such a problem if, instead of nesting the title itself between hyperlink tags, such as `## <a id=Univariate-+-One-step-ahead>Univariate</a>`, one just uses an unfilled hyperlink tag (`<a id=Univariate-+-One-step-ahead></a>`) before (or after) setting the title itself. After all, the point is to go to the title cell once the link is clicked, not if the title acts as the linked object itself.

Comment: Doesn't work in DataSpell