# How to create links to different sections in ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I tried to create links to different sections in ipython notebook.

I used the below code:

```
[Second Section](#Second-Section)
```

The above code creates a link to the Second Section and it run successfully in my jupyter notebook, however, when I tried to use the same code in ipython in kaggle competitions, it did not work.

Do you have an idea why it did not work on kaggle ipython notebook while it worked in jupyter notebook.

Comment: did you ask Kaggle?

Comment: I think there is no space to ask such questions in kaggle, unless the questions are related to the competitions themselves.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference a IPython notebook cell in markdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080066/how-to-reference-a-ipython-notebook-cell-in-markdown)