# How do you link to a slide in a Jupyter Notebook saved as Reveal.JS?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, reveal.js

When I download a Jupyter Notebook as slides, the links are not active (i.e. they don't take you anywhere). How do I link a table of contents page to the respective slides?

Linking to a cell can be done by anchoring it and then calling it later [see answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28080529/9286096) (e.g. place`<a id="another_cell"></a>` in the desired cell to jump to and place `[Another Cell](#another_cell)` where you'd click "Another Cell"). This works fine in an download of the Reveal.JS as a PDF, but not when doing slides.

Current code to publish with `nbconvert`:

```sh
jupyter nbconvert SOME_NOTEBOOK.ipynb
--to slides
--output-dir .\SOME_FOLDER
--SlidesExporter.reveal_theme=serif
--SlidesExporter.reveal_scroll=True
--SlidesExporter.reveal_transition=none
--TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True
--TemplateExporter.exclude_output_prompt=True
--reveal-prefix=./lib/reveal.js-3.8.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<a href="#/2"> Slide number 2 </a>
```

Note:
The slide count starts after the slide that has the table of contents.

Comment: This works great. Anyone know how to programmatically compute the slide number at `nbconvert` time so that we don't need to hard-code the slide numbers?