# Julia on Jupyter Notebook: Link one cell with text in a markdown cell

Tags: jupyter-notebook, hyperlink, julia, anchor

is there a possibility to link the text in my markdown cell with a code-cell using julia? Trying to clear up my notebook a little. I created bullet points and want to link each of them to certain cells in the notebook (code and markdown).

I read something about using anchor tags, but I could only find info on that for python.

Comment: The Jupyter is just Jupyter, so for example this should work:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28080529/2960695